# Why is My While Loop Acting Like an Input?

Tags: python

I am making a tic-tac-toe game and I am trying to make it so if your input does not equal rock, paper, or scissors it will prompt you to re enter until you get it right, although when I run the code it asks you to re enter one time and then continues on, regardless of what you enter.

Here is my code:

```
import random

print("How many times would you like to play?")
repeat = input()
possible_choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
for x in range (int(float(repeat))):
  user_input = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
  if user_input != possible_choices:
    user_input = False
  else:
    user_input = True
  
  while user_input == False: 
    user_input = input("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors: ")
    if user_input == possible_choices:
      user_input = True
  
      
  computer_action = random.choice(possible_choices)
  print(f"\nYou chose {user_input}, computer chose {computer_action}.\n")
  if (computer_action == user_input):
    print(f"You both chose {user_input} it's a tie!")

  if (user_input == "rock") and (computer_action == "paper"):
    print("Paper beats rock, you lose!")

  if (user_input == "rock") and (computer_action == "scissors"):
    print("Rock beats scissors, you win!")

  if (user_input == "paper") and (computer_action == "scissors"):
    print("Scissors beats paper, you lose!")

  if (user_input == "scissors") and (computer_action == "paper"):
    print("Scissors beats paper, you win!")
    print("")

  if (user_input == "paper") and (computer_action == "rock"):
    print("Paper beats rock, you win!")
  
print("Game ended.")
```

Comment: What part of this game has anything to do with tic-tac-toe?

Comment: `user_input` is a string.  `possible_choices` is a list.  *These values can never be equal*.  `user_input in possible_choices` is the test you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redefine `user_input` inside the for loop. Since a string will evaluate to not False the loop will always break. Another thing, you should be checking if the input is *in* the possible choices, not equal to the whole list.

```
for x in range (int(repeat)):
    user_input = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    valid_input = False
    if user_input in possible_choices:
        valid_input = True
    while valid_input == False: 
        user_input = input("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors: ")
        if user_input in possible_choices:
            valid_input = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just adjust your user input like so to check if input is NOT in the possible choices

```
user_input = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
  if user_input not in possible_choices:
    user_input = False

 while user_input == False: 
    user_input = input("Please enter rock, paper, or scissors: ")
    if user_input == possible_choices:
      user_input = True
```

Your code is currently asking for the user input twice because it is not correctly matching equivalence from the string and array via `==`